# Dimension of matrix column space and null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am studying linear algebra opencourseware by gilbert strang.

This is the question posed.

```
Construct a matrix whose column space contains (1, 1, 0) and
(0, 1, 1) and whose nullspace contains (1, 0, 1) and (0, 0, 1).
```

Solution

```
Solution. (4 points) Not possible : Such a matrix A must be 3 × 3. Since the nullspace is supposed to
contain two independent vectors, A can have at most 3−2 = 1 pivots. Since the column space is supposed to
contain two independent vectors, A must have at least 2 pivots. These conditions cannot both be met!
```

The point i would like to check is. How did he come to the conclusion that the matrix must be a 3X3 matrix? Why cannot it be a 3 x 4 or any other matrix?

Comment: It's probably implicitly understood to be square.

Comment: @Thoth why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nullspace is a subset of the domain, the column space of the codomain. Both of those are $\mathbb R^3$, so the matrix must be $3\times3$.